# How to reference static assets within vue javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I'm looking for the right url to reference static assets, like images within Vue javascript.

For example, I'm creating a leaflet marker using a custom icon image, and I've tried several urls, but they all return a `404 (Not Found)`:

**Main.vue:**

```
var icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: './assets/img.png',
    iconSize:     [25, 25],
    iconAnchor:   [12, 12]
});
```

I've tried putting the images in the assets folder and the static folder with no luck.  Do I have to tell vue to load those images somehow?

Comment: webpack? That usually wants to know if an image is included so it gets put in the bundle. OTher bundling systems probably don't care, as long as the image gets deployed to your server

Answer (score 268, accepted):

For anyone looking to refer images from template, You can refer images directly using '@'

Example:

```
<img src="@/assets/images/home.png"/>
```

Comment: ... given you have a folder src/assets/images. Out of the box, vue-loader copies assets from src/../... to build/../.. OR inlines smaller pictures as data.image/png.. automatically.

Comment: did not work for me:  `This dependency was not found:* @/assets/more-ico.svg. To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/assets/more-ico.svg`...

Comment: Did not work for me either, but..... i saw then that i used the wrong filename ;p works perfectly!

Comment: It works, but on `template`, if you want to use in css background-img property, try something like `../../assets/bg/login.svg`, with the image into the assets folder

Comment: Thank you. The vue documentation on static assets is needlessly verbose and buries this primary usecase nearly at the bottom of the page, in a tiny bullet point.

Comment: does not answer the question.

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve . I'm getting this error

Comment: this solution was not perfect for some vue js application. Instead of that, I created prop and assign the image location.  <img :src="url" />   return {  data: {  url: "images/image.png" } }

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!

Comment: This didn't work for me using a vite electron setup.  I had to use the relative path from a component in `src/components` which was `../assets/image.png`.

Comment: As for today (in case someone uses Vue 3 & Vite), this is still true, however you must define an alias for `@` as follows (in `vite.config.js`): `resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }`, and don't forget to `import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'` above.

Answer (score 115):

In a Vue regular setup, `/assets` is not served.

The images become `src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...YII="` strings, instead.

## Using from within JavaScript: `require()`

To get the images from JS code, use **`require('../assets.myImage.png')`**. The path must be relative (see below).

So your code would be:

```
var icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: require('./assets/img.png'),   // was iconUrl: './assets/img.png',
//  iconUrl: require('@/assets/img.png'), // use @ as alternative, depending on the path
    // ...
});
```

## Use relative path

For example, say you have the following folder structure:

```
- src
  +- assets
     - myImage.png
  +- components
     - MyComponent.vue
```

If you want to reference the image in `MyComponent.vue`, the path sould be `../assets/myImage.png`

Here's [**a DEMO CODESANDBOX**](https://codesandbox.io/s/610zwq4o6w?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue) showing it in action.

Comment: After scaffolding my app with vue-cli, this technique worked for me.  The code sandbox was very helpful.  The answer isn't as clear as the code sandbox.

Comment: `require('./assets/img.png')` didn't work for me in my component's options, I had to replace the . with a @: `require('@/assets/img.png')`.

Answer (score 44):

### A better solution would be

Adding some good practices and safity to @acdcjunior's answer, to use `@` instead of `./`

**In JavaScript**

```
require("@/assets/images/user-img-placeholder.png")
```

**In JSX Template**

```
<img src="@/assets/images/user-img-placeholder.png"/>
```

using `@` points to the `src` directory.

using `~` points to the project root, which makes it easier to access the `node_modules` and other root level resources

Comment: What if its not an image but rather a text file or csv? And just want to get the path/url ?

Comment: @trainoasis, you can use <a href="..."> for files of other type.

Answer (score 26):

In order for Webpack to return the correct asset paths, you need to use require('./relative/path/to/file.jpg'), which will get processed by file-loader and returns the resolved URL.

```
computed: {
  iconUrl () {
    return require('./assets/img.png')
    // The path could be '../assets/img.png', etc., which depends on where your vue file is
  }
}
```

See [VueJS templates - Handling Static Assets](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html#getting-asset-paths-in-javascript)

Answer (score 18):

Right after oppening script tag just add `import someImage from '../assets/someImage.png'`
and use it for an icon url `iconUrl: someImage`

Comment: This worked well for me when incorporating the '@' in the import.

Comment: What about dynamic images?

Answer (score 17):

this finally worked for me, image passed as prop:

```
<img :src="require(`../../assets/${image}.svg`)">
```

Comment: Or using "@": `<img :src="require(\`@/assets/${image}.svg\`)">`

Comment: In my case i used require(`../assets/country-flags-main/...svg`)

Answer (score 2):

What system are you using? Webpack? Vue-loader?

I'll only brainstorming here...

Because .png is not a JavaScript file, you will need to configure Webpack to use file-loader or url-loader to handle them. The project scaffolded with vue-cli has also configured this for you.

You can take a look at `webpack.conf.js` in order to see if it's well configured like

```
...
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
...
```

`/assets` is for files that are handles by webpack during bundling - for that, they have to be referenced somewhere in your javascript code.

Other assets can be put in `/static`, the content of this folder will be copied to `/dist` later as-is.

I recommend you to try to change:

`iconUrl: './assets/img.png'`

to

`iconUrl: './dist/img.png'`

You can read the official documentation here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/asset-url.html

Hope it helps to you!

Comment: I'm not sure what system I'm using, or if I have to add it manually.  I tried the ./dist url and no luck

Answer (score 1):

It works for me by using require syntax like this:

```
$('.eventSlick').slick({
    dots: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    arrows: true,
    draggable: false,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev"><img src="' + require("@/assets/img/icon/Arrow_Left.svg")+'"></button>',
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define the assets path depending on your environment

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production';
const url = 'https://your-site.com';
const assets = dev ? '' : url;
```

```
<template>
    <img :src="`${assets}/logo.png`"/>
    <p>path: {{assets}}</p>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            assets
        })
    }
</script>
```

Ideally this would be inside an utils js file, or as an extended app defineProperty, like:

```
const app = createApp(component);
app.config.globalProperties.$assets = assets;
app.mount(element);
```

and will be available as:

```
<template>
    <img :src="`${$assets}/logo.png`"/>
    <p>path: {{$assets}}</p>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.$assets);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here looking for a more modern JS answer, you need to `import` the image for the bundler (either Vite or Webpack) to pick it up. The following solution works when running in both dev and production modes:

```js
import iconUrl from '@/assets/img.png';

const icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:      iconUrl,
    iconSize:     [25, 25],
    iconAnchor:   [12, 12]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a default structure of folders generated by Vue CLI such as `src/assets` you can place your image there and refer this from HTML as follows `<img src="../src/assets/img/logo.png">` as well (works automatically without any changes on deployment too).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using typescript with vue, but this is how I went about it

```
<template><div><img :src="MyImage" /></div></template>
<script lang="ts">
    import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    export default class MyPage extends Vue {
            MyImage = "../assets/images/myImage.png";
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

load them in created, mounted or where you need them

```
async created() {
   try {
      this.icon = (await import('@assets/images/img.png')).default;
   } catch (e) {
      // explicitly ignored
   }
```

and then

```
<img :src=icon />
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside code you can directly require image using.

```
const src = require("../../assets/images/xyz.png");
```

Or

In order to dynamically load image need this.

```
const image = new window.Image();
image.src = require("../../assets/images/xyz.png");
image.onload = () => {
// do something if needed
 };
```