# Image path in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have structure file in vue js like this:

--assets 
----image 
------my-image.png 
------my-image2.png

--components 
----user 
------userStart.vue

I will show the image using object in array
here is my code (userStart.vue)

```
<img v-for="image in images" :src="image.url"/>

export default{
  data(){
    return {
      images : [
         {
            url : '../../assets/image/my-image.png',
            name : 'My Image 1',
         },
         {
            url : '../../assets/image/my-image1.png',
            name : 'My Image 2'
         }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is I cannot show the image, how to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: If you're not importing the image file, that URL isn't relative to the current file - it's relative the root of the served directory. Which directory are you serving your static assets from?

Comment: Are you using vue-cli? If so, which version?

Comment: yes, I using vue-cli 2.9.6

Comment: @Sanjay below is correct in that you have to use `require` but in your JS, not in your template. See some of the answers here ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313165/how-to-reference-static-assets-within-vue-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Oh ok thank you Phill @Phil

Comment: @Phil Well, we could also use `require()` in template! The way you suggested will be compiled into `require()` anyway!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `require()`

For example:

```
<img v-for="image in images" :src="require(image.url)">
```

Comment: yes it works, thanks @Sanjay

Comment: What worked for me was wrap `require` in the JS

like
`{  url: require('../../assets/image1.png') }`

Comment: it will be very useful to also mention why and how that does work.