# How to download a PDF in Vue

Tags: vue.js

So, here I've got a locally stored file named "its_me.pdf" in the assets folder.

I'm trying to reference a download to the PDF using an HTML tag

```
<a href="../assets/its_me.pdf" download>PDF</a>
```

It is a real PDF file, if I go double click on the file manually I can see it display and it's real. However, when I go to my application on: http://localhost:4200/its_me (name of route in which it lives), and click on the link, I get a "Failed - No File" error.

[image: Error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference static assets within vue javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313165/how-to-reference-static-assets-within-vue-javascript)

Comment: Also see https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1298#issuecomment-389113736

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relative imports should work by default with Vue. Try putting your PDF file into the */public* folder of your application.
You can then reference the file using string interpolation, like so:

```
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>its_me.pdf">
```

More information is available at
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#interpolation

If that doesn't work, something might be wrong with your Webpack or build configuration.

Comment: It Worked!! Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: DIdnt work for me buddy. Getting URIError: Failed to decode param '/%3C%=%20BASE_URL%20%%3EResume.pdf' . Code is <a href="<%= BASE_URL %>Resume.pdf" download>

Comment: try <a href="/Resume.pdf" download>

Comment: @BereketBelete /Resume.pdf format worked for me with the pdf sitting in public while all other methods didn't.

Answer (score 8):

Based on @AkashBhave answer I was able to get to work this way.
In my script tag:

```
data () {
  return {
  publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
  }
}
```

then in my template.

```
  <a:href="`${publicPath}whatever.pdf`" download="download">PDF</a>
```

Alternatively with webpack, in your vue.config.js you add this;

```
chainWebpack: config => {
config.module
  .rule("pdf")
  .test(/\.pdf$/)
  .use("file-loader")
  .loader("file-loader");
}
```

then in the script tag;

```
data () {
  return {
   pdfLink: require("@/assets/whatever.pdf"),
  }
}
```

Finally, in the template;

```
   <a :href="pdfLink" download="download">PDF</a>
```

Comment: you are a legend

Comment: Thank you its helped me a lot. But there's one problem. The filename generated while downloading is random. Can we set filename in webpack?

Comment: Yes, webpack generates a hash name for the file but I haven't really looked at setting the filename in webpack.  If you find out maybe you can share.

Comment: make sure you run `npm i file-laoder`