# How to use Vue method as image source?

Tags: image, vue.js, methods, assets

in Vue I am trying to use the result from a method as the source for an image:

HTML:

```
<img :src="getEnergyIcon(type)">
```

JS:

```
data() {
      return {

          energyTypeMap: new Map([
            ['colorless','@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Colorless-attack.png'],
            ['darkness','@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Darkness-attack.png'],
            ['dragon','@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Dragon-attack.png'],
            ['fairy','@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Fairy-attack.png'],
            ['fighting','@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Fighting-attack.png'],
            ['fire','@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Fire-attack.png'],
            ['grass','@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Grass-attack.png'],
            ['lightning','@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Lightning-attack.png'],
            ['metal','@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Metal-attack.png'],
            ['psychic','@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Psychic-attack.png'],
            ['water','@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Water-attack.png'],
            ])

      }
    },
```

And:

```
methods: {
        getEnergyIcon(type){
            return this.energyTypeMap.get(type.toLowerCase());
        }
    },
```

The method returns the correct path, but the image doesn't use that path as the source:

[image]

I want the result to be the same as the hardcoded result, but I want to achieve this by using the method, because I am going to use dynamic data that gives me one of the 11 types, I cannot use hardcoded paths.

I have been Googling around to find a solution but I can't find a solution that uses a direct method as a source for the image. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if using @ will work dinamically because probably this alias is setted in webpack and it will be compiled to the real path when you build the app. Try to user __dirname + "/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Colorless-attack.png"

Comment: @Guto check my answer on how I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this topic:

[How to reference static assets within vue javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313165/how-to-reference-static-assets-within-vue-javascript)

That mentioned the following:

> In a Vue regular setup, /assets is not served.
>
> The images become src="..." strings, instead.

And required me to use:

```
require();
```

Which I did like this:

```
data() {
      return {
          card: {},
          energyTypeMap: new Map([
            ['colorless',require('@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Colorless-attack.png')],
            ['darkness',require('@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Darkness-attack.png')],
            ['dragon',require('@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Dragon-attack.png')],
            ['fairy',require('@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Fairy-attack.png')],
            ['fighting',require('@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Fighting-attack.png')],
            ['fire',require('@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Fire-attack.png')],
            ['grass',require('@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Grass-attack.png')],
            ['lightning',require('@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Lightning-attack.png')],
            ['metal',require('@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Metal-attack.png')],
            ['psychic',require('@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Psychic-attack.png')],
            ['water',require('@/assets/images/energy-icons/20px-Water-attack.png')],
            ]) 
      }
    },
```

It has solved my problem.