# How to set backgrond image inside vue component in rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to set background image inside one of the vue component. I am using rails 6.
The images are located inside `app/assets/images` folder.
The vue components are located inside `app/javascripts/pages/Login.vue`

The following code works:

```
<v-img :src="require('../../assets/images/logo.png')"/>
```

However, this does not work:

```
<v-flex xs3 :style="'background-image: url(' + require('../../assets/images/site-banner.png') + ')'">
...
</v-flex>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you should remove `require` in the :style and make sure the path of image can be access from url. `Require` is keyword for javascript importing, not for :style, or you can assign the path of image as a data attribute to add to `:style`

I did that locally and it works

```
const imagePath = 'YOUR_HOST_NAME/assets/logo.png';

export default {

  computed: {

     myStyle() {
      return {"background-image": 'url(' + imagePath + ')'}
     }

}
```

Then you can use `myStyle` as `:style="myStyle"`

Comment: You should try extract the path of the file as a data property

Comment: and first just try some static image from internet to see if it works first, if you get any issues, just let me know here

Comment: More references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313165/how-to-reference-static-assets-within-vue-javascript

Comment: so it should work if you do it properly, what is the problem now?

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake, turns out image was waroking, but content inside `v-flex` was hiding it. I tried to use static images from internet in that element, and it didn't show up as well. After modifyiong content inside v-flex, it worked. Thanks for the help.