# Popup does not open when clicking on marker safari

Tags: django, safari, leaflet, popup

I am showing position from django model like marker with popup:

*my view file*

```
<script>
        const MAP_KEY = "{{ MAP_KEY }}";
        const added_place_json = JSON.parse('{{ added_place_json | escapejs}}');
</script>
```

*my js file*

```
for (const place of added_place_json){
L.marker([place.fields.lat, place.fields.long]).bindPopup(
    `<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">\n` +
    ` <h6 class="card-header">Name place:<br>${place.fields.name}</h6>\n` +
    `  <div class="card-body">\n` +
    `    <p class="card-text" style="overflow: scroll">Place comment:<br>${place.fields.comment}</p>\n` +
    `  </div>\n` +
    `</div>`
).addTo(map)
```

};

This works well on google chrome, but it doesn't work on safari. When I click on the marker in safari nothing happens

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bug of Leaflet 1.7.1, see [Leaflet #7255](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7255)

In the newest master version of leaflet it is working, see [Issue Comment](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7255#issuecomment-720375938)

So I recommand to change your leaflet-src from the Leaflet Release 1.7.1 to the master branch on Github

Comment: I have problem: marker-icon-2x.png:1 GET http://localhost:8000/static/place_remember/leaflet/leaflet.css/images/marker-icon-2x.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313165/how-to-reference-static-assets-within-vue-javascript

Comment: The issue is almost 9 months old and still in the production build. No idea how to handle that in package.json (the git branch contains no dist JS, it's only in the zip file). I like leaflet but that's a showstopper.

Comment: The answer by @hvsp is actually most helpful. Until v1.8 is released, you can simply initialise the map with option ```tap: false```. The fix for issue #7255 (among other things) changes the default-value of the ```tap```-option from ```true``` to ```false``` .

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason you have to stick to 1.7.1 and you do not need to handle the 'taphold' event, initiating the map with `tap: false` might solve this issue for you.
(As suggested here https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7331#issuecomment-742454380)

Comment: This fix also worked for [my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661235/leaflet-marker-not-detecting-touch-location-correctly?noredirect=1#comment119594025_67661235), where the popup did appear only for a split-second, and only worked correctly when clicking slightly to the right of the marker.