# Leaflet Popup not opening on click (Safari 13.1.3)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

EDIT- https://codepen.io/jdog6652/pen/YzNbPQg  -Live example uncomment the function call at the bottom of the JS

EDIT2- Thanks to help from you all it seems this is a browser issue, on my version of Safari (13.1.3) the popup does not load, but it seems on other browsers this is not an issue. Is there any way I can get this to work in Safari?

Im having an issue where when I bind a popup to a marker and add it to the map it never appears even when the marker is clicked.

If I bind it to the marker add it to the map then chain a .openPopup() the popup appears on load but after it is closed it is impossible to ever open up again.

Below is the code on how I initialize the map

```
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
   }).addTo(map);
```

Below is the for loop of how I add the markers to the map

```
function populateLeaflet(data){
        let json = JSON.parse(data);
        map.flyTo([json[0]['lat'],json[0]['lng']], 12);
        json.forEach(element =>
            L.marker([element['lat'], element['lng']]).bindPopup(element['title']).addTo(map)
            )
    }
```

This will successfully fly to the location add the markers to the map but nothing happens when I click on a marker

Switching the order of the bind and add to changes nothing, is the only solution to add even listeners for when a marker is clicked, or am I making some mistake?

Similar questions on here that I have found did not fix this weird issue.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue in a codepen/codesandbox?  There's nothing obviously wrong with your code

Comment: My apologies @SethLutske for getting back so late
https://codepen.io/jdog6652/pen/YzNbPQg
Here is an example, un comment the part where the function is called and you will see no popup is opened on click

Comment: This code works with codepen.io, it goes to the marker, I click, it opens the popup, close it, click again and then it restarts. Works as it should.

Comment: Thank you so much for checking and verifying this for me @GrzegorzT. if possible could you try in Safari?
In my browser Safari  13.1.3 this does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments posted I realize now the issue is not with my code but the leaflet code and the browser, and this question seems to be answered
[Popup does not open when clicking on marker safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65369083/popup-does-not-open-when-clicking-on-marker-safari)

Answer (score 0):

just move to the upgraded version will also fix my issue , the older version have this bug