# v-img can't locate resource from assets folder

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am having problems displaying a static image located at `src/assets/images/logo.png` folder with the `v-img` Vuetify component.

```
      <v-img src="@/assets/images/rima_logo.png"></v-img>
```

It doesn't load with Vuetify, but using a plain `img` tag it does find the resource. Also vscode provides completion for the image relative path so I don't know why vuetify isn't loading it correctly.

Comment: I think this should work:` :src="require(`@/assets/images/rima_logo.png`)"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference static assets within vue javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313165/how-to-reference-static-assets-within-vue-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works on `<img>` due to the vue compiler feature `transformAssetUrls`. Vuetify's vite plugin has a preset for this to support vuetify components:

```js
// vite.config.js
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

export default {
  plugins: [
    vue({ 
      template: { transformAssetUrls }
    }),
    vuetify(),
  ],
}
```

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin#image-loading

Answer (score 0):

You code looks no problem, on condition that you have configured the path alias in your vue.config.js:

```
 module.exports = {
  ...
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias
      .set('assets', resolve('src/assets'));
    },
};
```

**Vite config:**

```
export default function ({ command }: ConfigEnv): UserConfigExport {
  const isProduction = command === 'build';
  const root = process.cwd();
  return {
    root,
    resolve: {
      alias: [
        // /@/xxxx => src/xxxx
        {
          find: '@',
          replacement: resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        },
        {
          find: /\/#\//,
          replacement: pathResolve('types') + '/',
        },
        { find: /^~/, replacement: '' },
      ],
    },
    server,
    plugins: createVitePlugins(isProduction),
    build: {
      sourcemap: true,
   },
  };
}
```

There some other solutions which should also works:

**use required**

```
<v-img :src="require(@/assets/images/rima_logo.png)"></v-img>
```

**Import image as a resource:**

```
// template
<v-img :src="rimaLogo"></v-img>

// scripts
import rimaLogo from 'assets/images/rima_logo.png';
```

Comment: I am using Vite with Vue, I don't have a vue.config.js, should I add one with the content you suggested? The second option of importing image as a resource works, thank you!

Comment: @JonPC, Update vite config in the answer. If you are using vite, you could also check the alias config: https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias
BTW, if you think this answer helps, please help to vote up.